# Button click a drop down is created using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I click a button and it displays a drop down whenever it changes I want to take it's value and replace it in the input field but If I create many drop downs  when I return to the first drop down and change its value the corresponding input field value can't be changed as it is depending on the button click number.

```
            <button type="button" id="buttonadd" onclick="addMore()">Add</button>
            <div id='container'> 
            </div>
            <script>
               var i = 0;
               var x = 0;
               var selectid = 0;
               var input2;
               var select;
               var button;
               var select_id;
               var input2_hiddenID;
               var input2hidden;
               var counter = 0;
               var select_value;
            function addMore()
            {       

                       if(counter >= 1 && (!select_value || select_value == 0)){
                        $("#buttonadd").prop('disabled', true);

                    }else{

                        select_value = 0;
                        button = document.getElementById('container');

                        select  = document.createElement("select");
                        select.options.add( new Option("...select...","0", true, true) );
                        select.options.add( new Option("name","1") );
                        select.options.add( new Option("phone","2") );
                        select.setAttribute("id","selectid" + selectid);

                        select_id = "selectid";
                        select.setAttribute("onchange", "getValue(select_id, selectid)");
                        button.appendChild(select);
                        input2 = document.createElement("input");

                        input2.setAttribute("type","hidden");
                        input2.setAttribute("id","x" + x);
                        input2.setAttribute("name","x" + x);
                        button.appendChild( input2 );

                        var linebreak1 = document.createElement("br");
                        var linebreak2 = document.createElement("br");
                        button.append(linebreak1, linebreak2);
                        i++;
                        x++;
                        selectid++; 
                        counter++;
                    }       
            }

            function getValue(selectid, a){

                    var lastId = a-1;

                    var data = selectid + lastId;

                    select_value = 
             document.getElementById(data).value;

                    var x= "x"+lastId;
                    input2hidden = document.getElementById(x);

                if(counter >= 1 && (!select_value || select_value == 0) ){

                    alert("Please choose from the select menu");
                    $("#buttonadd").prop('disabled', true);

                    input2hidden.value = select_value;

                }else {

                    $("#buttonadd").prop('disabled', false);

                        input2hidden.value = select_value;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood your problem well but give you a solution as to how I understand a dropdown with one click

**

> HTML

**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DropDown</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          No dropdown
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="button-dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
          Dropdown 1 <span>▼</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Drop Item 1
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Drop Item 2
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Drop Item 3
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          No dropdown
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="button-dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
          Dropdown 2 <span>▼</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              asdf
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**

> CSS

**

```
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.nav {
    display: block;
    font: 13px Helvetica, Tahoma, serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav .button-dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #999;
}

.nav li a:hover, .nav li a.dropdown-toggle.active {
    background-color: #289dcc;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav li a:hover span, .nav li a.dropdown-toggle.active span {
    color: #fff;
}

.nav li .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    text-align: left;
}

.nav li .dropdown-menu.active {
    display: block;
}

.nav li .dropdown-menu a {
    width: 150px;
}
```

**

> JavaScript

**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    function t(t) {
        e(t).bind("click", function (t) {
            t.preventDefault();
            e(this).parent().fadeOut()
        })
    }
    e(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
        var t = e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").is(":hidden");
        e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").hide();
        e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
        if (t) {
            e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").toggle().parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active")
        }
    });
    e(document).bind("click", function (t) {
        var n = e(t.target);
        if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown")) e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").hide();
    });
    e(document).bind("click", function (t) {
        var n = e(t.target);
        if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown")) e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks alot Erik but this not my problem the issue that when i click a button i create a drop down and an input field and when i click again another drop down with equivalant input field is created and so on.

Comment: and I take the value of this drop down onchange and put it in the input field the main problem if i created the drop down on the third click for example and go back to the first one i can't get the value of this first drop down.